# Failed a FirstPost audit on an API request

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

[Here is the audit I failed,](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9853220) from the first post queue.

My action was to flag the post as off-topic, because it was a request for an off-site resource.

From the  "STOP! Look and Listen":

> This was a high quality post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even upvoting.

--seems based on just the number of votes (+18 as of this submission), which I obviously cannot see during the review. I didn't bother to click through to view it directly.

Because I don't regularly frequent [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios), should I have just skipped the review? I'm sensing the mobile tags appear to have their own policies.

Comment: This looks like one of those cases where "API" doesn't refer to a third-party resource, but a built-in feature.

Comment: @BoltClock I see, okay. Perhaps I should have skipped. Is this exempt from the "find an off-site resource" option?

Comment: I don't know about that, but in this case I imagine the question could be reworded to something like "How do I capture Live Photos in my iOS 9 app?", doing away with the "off-site resource" issue altogether. Certainly not a good audit candidate, though.

Comment: @BoltClock I agree, maybe I should have clicked edit instead ;). Whelp, I'll continue reviewing in 7 days time.

Comment: Do disputed audits count still against the time-out from reviewing? Or can this notch be erased

Comment: That would be a question for Shog, I'm afraid.

Comment: @BoltClock mhm, thought as much. Thanks for the response!

Comment: "Because I don't regularly frequent [ios], should I have just skipped the review?" I think the die-hard [ios] regulars (of which I am not one) would probably answer "yes".

Comment: @Shoover Pending the result of this post, I may oblige. I wonder if we have existing discussions on these "city-state" tags. I'll take a look